# PHP array_combine() function not working properly?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to combine two array in PHP with array_combine() function, but sometimes it working fine and sometimes it's not. I can't understand why it's working like this!

***My Code:***

```
var_dump($selectedDuretion);
var_dump($selectedDuretionType);

$combination = array_combine($selectedDuretion, $selectedDuretionType);
return $combination;
```

***Expected OUTPUT:***

```
array(4)
{
    [0]=> string(1) "3"
    [1]=> string(2) "12"
    [2]=> string(1) "4"
    [3]=> string(1) "3"
}
array(4)
{
    [0]=> string(4) "days"
    [1]=> string(4) "days"
    [2]=> string(5) "weeks"
    [3]=> string(5) "weeks"
}

{"3":"days","12":"days","3":"weeks","4":"weeks"}
```

***Actual OUTPUT :***

```
array(4)
{
    [0]=> string(1) "3"
    [1]=> string(2) "12"
    [2]=> string(1) "4"
    [3]=> string(1) "3"
}
array(4)
{
    [0]=> string(4) "days"
    [1]=> string(4) "days"
    [2]=> string(5) "weeks"
    [3]=> string(5) "weeks"
}

{"3":"weeks","12":"days","4":"weeks"}
```

**The combination of arrays it shocking, I'll be thankful if anyone tell me why is this happening and how to solve it.**

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense, there are 2 entries with the key `3`. How would you address them?

Comment: Php arrays can't have duplicate keys, so it there is a duplicate, ie `"3":"days", "3":"weeks"`, then the 2nd value will overwrite the 1st value, resulting in only the 2nd value, in this case `"3":"weeks"`.

Comment: You can 't create array with similar index / keys.

Comment: array key must be unique

Answer (score 1):

PHP Does not allow you to have duplicate indices in an array while JSON does allow you to have that for whatever reasons.

Since you are trying to convert PHP arrays to JSON your duplicate key gets eliminated. Hence you will have to manually build the JSON string.

```
$json="";
for($i=0;$i<count($selectedDuration);$i++)
{
   $json.='"'.$selectedDuration[$i].'":"'.$selectedDurationType[$i].'",';
}
$json=rtrim($json,",");
$json="{".$json."}";

echo $json;
```

**Output**

```
{"3":"days","12":"days","4":"weeks","3":"weeks"}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/577399)**

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hanky Panky and I hope you never discourage your junior in future.